# Переменная в функцию для post запроса и получения ответа

Tags: javascript, функции, переменные

*отправляю на другой файл значение input, 
получаю обратно ответ и подсовываю его в div*

---

хром ошибок не показывает, алерт показывает что в переменной значение `#window`
но в div ничего не приходит ((
наверняка какая-то глупая неточность, не могу понять!

---

у меня несколько запросов, хотел сделать функцию, заодно потрениться, но не работает у меня эта конструкция. а так, сама по себе конструкция работает...

вот не хочет никак мне даться этот JS, подскажите как заставить это работать?
я так понимаю с помощью return; надо это дело в глобал перевести, но никак не выкуплю как, мне-то нужно чтобы результат еще в div попал...

- учусь, не хотел дурацкие вопросы задавать, но вот пришлось -

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var i_dir = 'window';
    var id_dir = '#' + i_dir;
    //alert(id_dir);

    function my_dir(i_dir) {
      $.post(
        'sys/' + i_dir + '.php',
        function(msg) {
          $(id_dir).html(msg);
        }
      );
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="window"></div>
```

Comment: А php-файл что отдаёт?

Comment: html, сам по себе запрос работает! просто уж очень хочется разобраться в js, а не просто тупо без понимания копировать чужой код... хотя без понимания и тут куча трудностей...

Comment: как вы вызываете функцию `my_dir`?

Comment: Во-первых, знак решетки в URL передается не напрямую, а как [%23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: mix, блин я сутки не спал, совсем забыл ее вызвать )))) все заработало ) спасибо! стыд-то какой )))))

KrasPvP, спасибо, буду знать! ) хотя и так завелось